# In Python how would I compare with multiple values using custom keys?

Tags: python

When implementing the `__eq__` and `__lt__` methods of a class, it is common practice to use tuples to group the values you wish to compare, like so:

```
@total_ordering
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.c, self.a, self.b))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.c, self.a, self.b) == (other.c, other.a, other.b)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return (self.c, self.a, self.b) < (other.c, other.a, other.b)
```

However this uses the natural ordering of each key. What if I want to change, for example, how `a` sorts?

This is what I've come up with so far, and while it seems to work OK, I was wondering if there is a better way to go about it:

```
@total_ordering
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = MyA(a) # Note
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.c, self.a, self.b))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.c, self.a, self.b) == (other.c, other.a, other.b)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return (self.c, self.a, self.b) < (other.c, other.a, other.b)

class MyA(A):
    def __hash__(self):
        # ...

    def __eq__(self, other):
        # ...

    def __lt__(self, other):
        # ...
```

Subclassing `A` lets me define my custom ordering, and allows `MyA` to behave like a regular `A` in every other way which is nice, but it seems wasteful / needlessly verbose especially if I have to do this for multiple fields.

**Edit:** As per user1320237's answer below, this is what I've come up with:

```
@total_ordering
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.c, self.a, self.b))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (0, 0, 0) == (cmp(self.c, other.c),
                             cmpA(self.a, other.a),
                             cmp(self.b, other.b))

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return (0, 0, 0) > (cmp(self.c, other.c),
                            cmpA(self.a, other.a),
                            cmp(self.b, other.b))

def cmpA(a1, a2):
    # ...
```

(Note the `>` in `__lt__` since `cmp(x, y)` returns `-1` if `x < y` and `__lt__` should return `True`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you want to order with list.sort() for example you can pass arguments to it:

Your code:

```
...
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return (self.c, self.a, self.b) < (other.c, other.a, other.b)

...
list.sort()
```

equivalent:

```
list.sort(key = lambda self: (self.c, self.a, self.b))
```

also equivalent:

```
list.sort(cmp = lambda self, other: \
                (self.c, self.a, self.b) < (other.c, other.a, other.b))
```

so if you want to sort your answers in different ways i would propose:

```
class Foo(object):
    @staticmethod
    def cmp_absoluteOrder(self, other):
        return (self.c, self.a, self.b) < (other.c, other.a, other.b)

    @staticmethod
    def cmp_otherOrder(self, other):
        return ...

    @staticmethod
    def cmp_combinedSort(cmpA, cmpB, cmpC):
        return lambda self, other: (0, 0, 0) < (cmpA(self.c, other.c), cmpA(self.a, other.a), cmpA(self.b, other.b), )

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.c) ^ hashA(self.a) ^ hash(self.b)

...
list.sort(cmp = Foo.cmp_absoluteSorting)
list.sort(cmp = Foo.cmp_combinedSort(cmp, (lambda a1, a2: ...), cmp))

hashA = hash # or replace it if important # but the same a will retunrn the same hash
```

or something like this

Comment: Oh, this is interesting! `(0, 0, 0) < (cmpC(..), cmpA(...), cmpB(...))` might be exactly what I'm looking for. I should be able to put that into `__lt__`. Am I correct in assuming something like `(0, 0, 0) == (...)` should go in `__eq__`?

Comment: Ok, take a look at my edit; I've integrated your suggestion into my code. Now if I can figure out how to write `__hash__` I'll mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

If this is just a one off action, something like the following will work:

```
def custom_sorter(foo):
   """Takes Foo objects and gives a representation for sorting."""
   return (foo.c, A(foo.a), foo.b)

sorted(foo_list, key=custom_sorter)
```

If it is going to be done many times, you may either consider a class method on `Foo` that will be extensible and spit out prototypes similar to `custom_sorter`.

If you are using the **same** custom sorter many times, why not just make it part of the class?

You really just need to ask yourself *why* and *do I really need to*.

Comment: Should that be `MyA(foo.a)` in your example? If so, then moving the sorting into a seperate function doesn't help things since I still need the custom subclass. As you suggest I think it's best to keep the sort inside `Foo`, instead of having to pass `key=...` to `sorted()` every time I want to sort a bunch of `Foo`s.

Comment: It can be whatever you like, it is custom.